# If statement in C not working correctly

Tags: c

I am currently learning C and I'm having trouble with this if statement.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age = 18;
    int ageToVote = 18;

    if(age >= ageToVote)
    return 0;
    {
        printf("You are old enough to vote.\n");
    }
}
```

I have been told that the above code should give me the output of: You are old enough to vote.

But for some reason it will only give me that output when I change `int age = 18` to `int age  = 17` , or any other number lower than 18.

This obviosuly does not make sense because the code says if the age is greater than or equal to the agetovote value of 18 then the output should be You are old enough to vote.

Any ideas why it is displaying the correct output when the math is incorrect?

Comment: The body of your if is `return 0;` not the following `{...}`, this is a really basic feature of *C*.

Comment: I love these "XY core language feature not working" questions... surely the compiler/the language is faulty... >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because compound statement

```
{
    printf("You are old enough to vote.\n");
}
```

never get executed.  Remove `return 0;` after `if` statement.

```
if(age >= ageToVote)
{
    printf("You are old enough to vote.\n");
}
```

Comment: If you had an `else` condition, you would have had a compilation error...

Comment: I think the return value is still giving me trouble.

Comment: What trouble? Any error or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int age = 18;
    int ageToVote = 18;

    if(age >= ageToVote)
    {
        printf("You are old enough to vote.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That amounts to:

```
if(18 >= 18)
    return 0;
```

Of *course* `18 >= 18`, so of *course* it returns immediately.

> I have been told that the above code should give me the output of: You are old enough to vote.

Whoever told you that was incorrect. The `return` keyword causes the function to exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

return 0; must be the last statement in your method.

If you put return 0; after IF and before {} you'execute that and so you'll ignore the remains statement.